# how just by implementing an interface subclass acquires the behaviour

Tags: java, interface, implements

I always wonder how just by implementing an interface , sub class acquires the behavior. For example if I implement Runnable interface my subclass start behaving as thread, but what if I implement all the methods defined in interface Runnable but not write "implementing Runnable", subclass doesn't behave as Thread. Same with EventListeners . Please help me understanding this behavior.

Comment: "For example if I implement Runnable interface my subclass start behaving as thread" is wrong; interfaces are just contracts.

Comment: Please check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966044/java-threading-how-does-implementing-runnable-work-for-threading

Answer (score 2):

By implementing an interface I, you're declaring that the Object "is a" I and that it'll contain all the methods defined by this interface. If you just implement the methods of the interface I, but don't declare it by an implement statement, compiler won't be able to determine that your class "is a" I and you won't be able to use it as a I-type.

Answer (score 1):

No, `Runnable` has nothing to do with behaving like a thread. It just contains a plain, simple, void nullary method called "run".

Not specifying `implements Runnable` will just make your object not an instance of the `Runnable` type, which means you won't be able to pass it to a method requiring a `Runnable`. This is just an issue of type safety. The method you call could also accept an `Object` and invoke `run` using reflection, with the exact same behavior.

Comment: So is the method "run" of my thread is invoked through reflection in java? Sorry I am new to java..

Comment: @user1147070 - The `java.lang.Thread` class is defined as part of the standard library, and one way of constructing a `Thread` is to pass in an instance of `Runnable`.  The Thread code knows that it can call `Runnable.run()`, because that method is defined on the interface - no reflection needed.  Marking your class as `implements Runnable` just lets the compiler, and other classes, know that they can "treat it like a Runnable".  It doesn't as such inherit any behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea about Runnable. But many a times just by implementing an interface subclass start behaving like that. Is that through reflection and how?

Comment: No, your idea is wrong. `implements interface` doesn't add absolutely any behavior to a class: it just forces that class to define all the methods of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

When you are implementing `Runnable` your class does not become thread and does not start behavior as thread. However if your class implements `Runnable` you can run it in context of thread:

```
class MyClass1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // this stuff will run in thread when thread's start() method is called
    }
}

new Thread(new MyClass1()).start();
```

But java is strongly typed language. You can just create class like this:

```
class MyClass2 {
    public void run() {
        // this stuff will run in thread when thread's start() method is called
    }
}
```

But it will not be `Runnable`. Therefore you cannot just send it to thread:

```
new Thread(new MyClass2()).start();
```

In this case you will get compilation error. Compiler cannot know that your class indeed implements method that looks like one that is declared in `Runnable`. You must declare this (as in first case).

Answer (score 1):

A `Runnable` only allows your class to be run in a Thread. You still need e.g. a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to actually run it in an actual Thread.

However, you can `extend Thread` which would allow you to call `Thread.start()`.

To actually get out behavior from just implementing an interface, you would need a second object inspecting the classpath for classes implementing your interface using reflection, and then do something with that class.

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea first idea that why we implement Runnable. Can you please elaborate a little about how can we can get the behavior from just implementing an interface through reflection.

Comment: You could scan all the classes (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection for that) for a specific interface, instantiate them and, e.g call a method.

But as a note, it is very obscure to do it like that, better explicitly instantiate your classes and call the interface method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two aspect:

1. Interface as a contract: Interfaces imposes a **behavioral contract** on a class implementing it. For example, If `Car` is an interface with some methods **abstractly** defining a car, any class implementing `Car` interface will have to define the methods of the car. You are free to actually implement the behavior.
2. Analogy of `Runnable` acting as thread is incorrect. What makes `Runnable` class act as thread is the the `Thread class`. `Runnable` just specifies the contract for a class to act as thread. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966044/java-threading-how-does-implementing-runnable-work-for-threading).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a subclassing behavior. In order to use subclass behavior you need to extend the class.

W.r.t interfaces these are just templates/contracts that are implemented by class. In order for runnable to work calling program need to instantiate a thread and when thread will start it will call run method implemented by your class.

Answer (score 0):

> I always wonder how just by implementing an interface , sub class acquires the behavior.

It doesn't 'acquire' any 'behaviour'. The subclass *provides* the behaviour. What implementing the interface does is provide the compile-time type signatures such that you can use the subclass where the interface is specified.